# Calendar Class arithmetic anomaly

Tags: java, class, calendar

`cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,-6);` gave me a date of one and a half years back when run on 3 Dec 2012.

It gave the date 2 July 2011.

Please can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: What did you *expect* it to do? (And what documentation do you have to suggest that would be the right thing to do?) What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You probably wanted to use `cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6)` instead of `cal.set(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you set the month to `-6` relative to 2012.  And given that 0 means January, `-6` means July ... of the previous year.

The 'set' operation **sets** the designated field.  It doesn't increment or decrement the field.

---

Obligatory recommendation ... use Joda Time.

Answer (score 0):

cal.set() sets the month relative to the current year. As the current year is 2012, -6 takes it to 6 months back i.e. July 2011.
For proper behaviour, use either cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-6) or cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,6)